# How to maintain text size in a responsive SVG?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to maintain the size of text elements within a responsive d3.js chart.

I've set the viewBox and preserveAspectRatio attributes on the svg element to get the responsiveness, however this scales all of the svg elements including text. I've tried setting the font-size as both an attribute and in CSS, but the text elements continue to scale with the rest of the chart.

The responsiveness is done with the following:

```js
.attr("width", '100%')
.attr("height", '100%')
.attr('viewBox','0 0 600 300')
.attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMinYMin')
```

A jsfiddle of the chart is here: https://jsfiddle.net/w4x97nv0/1/

What would be the best way of fixing the font size of the text while scaling the other svg elements?

Comment: I think you'll have to explicitly set the tick styles, otherwise they inherit from the parent

Answer (score 4):

Your question is a bit strange: the font size is actually constant, 10px, all the time. What's happening, since you set the SVG `viewBox`, is that the SVG is stretching to its container.

So, by asking to keep the font size the same, it seems to me that you're actually asking how you can **change** it! I mean, change it to keep the same apparent size on the screen, regardless the size of the SVG.

If that is correct, you can execute a simple math in the `"resize"` listener. Like this:

```
d3.select(window).on("resize", function() {
    const newWidth = d3.select("svg").style("width");
    const newFontSize = 10 * (600 / parseInt(newWidth));
    d3.selectAll(".tick").select("text")
        .style("font-size", newFontSize)
});
```

As you can see, we get the new width of the SVG and, using `600` as the original width, we calculate the new font size. It's not a very nice effect, visually speaking, and again I'm not sure why you want that.

Here is your JSFiddle with that change: https://jsfiddle.net/2vk1dqtz/

Comment: "I'm not sure why you want that": because text has different accessibility than the rest of the chart? e.g. if the chart is resized to be very small, you might want the bars/etc. to become smaller but the labels to stay the same so they're readable.